# Dynamically set local variable

Tags: python, dynamic

How do you dynamically set local variable in Python (where the variable name is dynamic)?

Comment: You're doing it wrong if the variable name is dynamic.

Comment: I once programmed to read chemical species name from input file and then create objects for those species name taking what I read from text file.  In this way i can say H2O.mwt, something like that.  there could be a legitimate reason to do this, IMHO.

Comment: I am aware this is bad practice. But in some conditions it may be a dirty shortcut. Besides, it's interesting, it shows how dynamic the language can really be. It's also good that the feedback is here so readers won't use it readily, but that's not a valid reason for a down-vote.

Comment: The fast locals array is coupled to the code object (i.e. co_varnames, co_nlocals). It's fixed. `locals()` is just calling [PyFrame_FastToLocals](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/frameobject.c#l866) to create a dict view of the current values. You can dynamically update the fast locals based on this dict if you use `ctypes` to call [PyFrame_LocalsToFast](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/frameobject.c#l918) on the current frame (`sys._getframe(0)`).

Comment: @eryksun - that sounds like the start of a complete and insightful answer - if you'll compile it to one, I'll accept it

Comment: @Jonathan: Using the C API isn't a good solution. It does let you dynamically update a local in a function (I don't see the point of creating one) in Python 2 and 3, but it's 'hacky'. Even the answer from @kindall doesn't work in Python 3 (the compiled bytecode still uses `LOAD_GLOBAL`). There's been no attempt to facilitate this in a standard way as far as I know.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Contrary to other answers already posted you cannot modify `locals()` directly and expect it to work.

```
>>> def foo():
    lcl = locals()
    lcl['xyz'] = 42
    print(xyz)


>>> foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    foo()
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 4, in foo
    print(xyz)
NameError: global name 'xyz' is not defined
```

Modifying `locals()` is undefined. Outside a function when `locals()` and `globals()` are the same it will work; inside a function it will *usually* not work.

Use a dictionary, or set an attribute on an object:

```
d = {}
d['xyz'] = 42
print(d['xyz'])
```

or if you prefer, use a class:

```
class C: pass

obj = C()
setattr(obj, 'xyz', 42)
print(obj.xyz)
```

**Edit**:
Access to variables in namespaces that aren't functions (so modules, class definitions, instances) are usually done by dictionary lookups (as Sven points out in the comments there are exceptions, for example classes that define `__slots__`). Function locals can be optimised for speed because the compiler (usually) knows all the names in advance, so there isn't a dictionary until you call `locals()`.

In the C implementation of Python `locals()` (called from inside a function) creates an ordinary dictionary initialised from the current values of the local variables. Within each function any number of calls to `locals()` will return the same dictionary, but every call to `locals()` will update it with the current values of the local variables. This can give the impression that assignment to elements of the dictionary are ignored (I originally wrote that this was the case). Modifications to existing keys within the dictionary returned from `locals()` therefore only last until the next call to `locals()` in the same scope.

In IronPython things work a bit differently. Any function that calls `locals()` inside it uses a dictionary for its local variables so assignments to local variables change the dictionary and assignments to the dictionary change the variables **BUT** that's only if you explicitly call `locals()` under that name. If you bind a different name to the `locals` function in IronPython then calling it gives you the local variables for the scope where the name was bound and there's no way to access the function locals through it:

```
>>> def foo():
...     abc = 123
...     lcl = zzz()
...     lcl['abc'] = 456
...     deF = 789
...     print(abc)
...     print(zzz())
...     print(lcl)
...
>>> zzz =locals
>>> foo()
123
{'__doc__': None, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'zzz': <built-in function locals>, 'foo': <function foo at 0x000000000000002B>, '__name__': '__main__', 'abc': 456}
{'__doc__': None, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'zzz': <built-in function locals>, 'foo': <function foo at 0x000000000000002B>, '__name__': '__main__', 'abc': 456}
>>>
```

This could all change at any time. The only thing guaranteed is that you cannot depend on the results of assigning to the dictionary returned by `locals()`.

Comment: Two minor corrections: 1. The return value of `locals()` is a standard dictionary in CPython 2.x and 3.x, which can be changed as usual (but the changes to propagate back to the local scope). 2. Access to class and instance namespaces doesn't always involve a dictionary look-up.  There are several exceptions, including instances of classes that define `__slots__`.

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach, I've updated my answer a bit on your second point.  What I wrote on the first point is sufficiently specific that I'm sure I must have tested it, so either I confused myself totally or perhaps it varies by Python version. I'll check again and update the answer in a bit.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I figured it out: multiple calls to `locals()` in the same function return the same dictionary and overwrite existing keys each time you call it so because I mixed multiple calls to `locals()` with printing the dictionary it originally returned it looked to me as though it wasn't changing. I've explained this possible pitfall in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: can you get to the point? How do I update the variables in a namespace? for me `locals.update(d)` did not work: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: @CharlieParker, functions usually work better when you call them. In this case however I would suggest you stop trying to update the local variables: just store your values in a `dict`.

Comment: @Duncan but why? Why is that better? I see no benefit except that now I'm forced to use a dictionary for some random reason, unmotivated reason (to me).

Comment: @CharlieParker it is better because if you don't know the name of a local in advance there is no way to access it except through the `locals()` dict, and no way to be sure you haven't overwritten or hidden another local or even a global name. Using a `dict` it is safe to store any strings as keys.

Comment: @Duncan I always thought python was a language for consenting adults. If one uses `exec` or overwrites `locals()` one takes the risks of the things you mentioned (overwriting things for example). If one knows for sure that loading variables to locals and what the names are one can just use those variables later, the compiler has an issue if they have not been pre-defined a-priori. I personally don't see the big deal, one can always re-write gobals like `for = 'breaking for keyword'` without the need the help of overwriting locals. I guess I don't appreciate the real issue or something...

Comment: @CharlieParker sure, you're a consenting adult so go ahead and break things, just don't say you weren't warned.

And no, you can't assign to reserved words like `for`.

Answer (score 30):

Others have suggested assigning to `locals()`. This won't work inside a function, where locals are accessed using the `LOAD_FAST` opcode, *unless* you have an `exec` statement somewhere in the function. To support this statement, which could create new variables that are not known at compile time, Python is then forced to access local variables by name within the function, so writing to `locals()` works. The `exec` can be out of the code path that is executed.

```
def func(varname):
    locals()[varname] = 42
    return answer           # only works if we passed in "answer" for varname
    exec ""                 # never executed

func("answer")
>>> 42
```

Note: This only works in Python 2.x. They did away with this foolishness in Python 3, and other implementations (Jython, IronPython, etc.) may not support it either.

This is a bad idea, though. How will you access the variables if you don't know their name? By `locals()[xxx]` probably. So why not just use your own dictionary rather than polluting `locals()` (and taking the chance of overwriting a variable your function actually needs)?

Answer (score 8):

(Just a quick note for others googlin')

Ok, so modifying `locals()` [is not the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/558008) ( while modifying `globals()` [is supposed to work](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)). In the meantime, `exec` *could be*, but it's painfully slow, so, as with regular expressions, we may want to `compile()` it first:

```
# var0 = 0; var1 = 1; var2 = 2
code_text = '\n'.join( "var%d = %d" % (n, n) for n in xrange(3) )

filename = ''
code_chunk = compile( code_text, filename, 'exec' )

# now later we can use exec:
exec code_chunk # executes in the current context
```

Comment: ... and why would you ever do this if you can just use a dictionary?

Comment: "I'm aware this isn't good practice, and the remarks are legit, but this doesn't make it a bad question, just a more theoretical one" (q) TS  

-- takes quite a while to explain. and it's a different question. let's say this answer is safe to ignore in most cases )  

ps. and isn't it good that *if* you'll decide you need it, it would be there?

Answer (score 3):

<s>You could modify `locals()` directly:</s>

```
locals()['foo'] = 'bar'
```

But a better way would be to have some dict that holds all your dynamic variable names as dictionary keys:

```
d = {}
for some in thing:
    d[some] = 'whatever'
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting modifying `locals()`

Comment: @Duncan: If you read carefully, I didn’t suggest doing it. I merely said that one *could* do it, but that there is a better way.

Comment: Saying you *could* do it is what I'm objecting to. From the docs: `Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.`

Comment: -1 modifying locals() doesn't work.

Comment: `locals()['foo'] = 'bar'` works in python 2.7 and 3, was this changed at some time?

Answer (score 3):

I've spent the last... couple hours, I guess, trying to hack around the lack of function closures, and I came up with this, which might help:

```
common_data = ...stuff...
def process(record):
    ...logic...

def op():
    for fing in op.func_dict: # Key line number 1
        exec(fing + " = op.func_dict[fing]") # Key line number 2

    while common_data.still_recieving:
        with common_data._lock:
            if common_data.record_available:
                process(common_data.oldest_record)
        time.sleep(1.0)

op.func_dict.update(locals()) # Key line number 3
threading.Thread(target = op).start()

...
```

It's a pretty heavy handed / contrived example, but if there are a lot of locals or you're still in the process of prototyping this pattern becomes useful.  Mostly I was just bitter about all the data stores being replicated or moved in order to handle callback delegates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local dictionary and put all the dynamic bindings as items into the dictionary. Then knowing the name of such a "dynamic variable" you can use the name as the key to get its value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say We have the below dictionary:

```
DictionaryA = {'No Rating': ['Hobbit', 'Movie C', 'Movie G'],
               'Forget It': ['Avenger', 'Movie B'], 
               'Must See': ['Children of Men', 'Skyfall', 'Movie F'], 
               '3': ['X-Men', 'Movie D'],
               '2': ['Captain America', 'Movie E'], 
               '4': ['Transformers', 'Movie A']}
```

I want to create new dictionaries as below:

```
NewDictionary1 = {'No Rating': ['Hobbit', 'Movie C', 'Movie G']} 
NewDictionary2 = {'Forget It': ['Avenger', 'Movie B']} 
NewDictionary3 = {'Must See': ['Children of Men', 'Skyfall', 'Movie F']}
```

a oneliner:

```
dics = [{k:v} for k,v in DictionaryA.iteritems()]
```

would be outputted to:

```
[{'Must See': ['Children of Men', 'Skyfall', 'Movie F']}, {'Forget It': ['Avenger', 'Movie B']}, {'No Rating': ['Hobbit', 'Movie C', 'Movie G']}, {'3': ['X-Men', 'Movie D']}, {'2': ['Captain America', 'Movie E']}, {'4': ['Transformers', 'Movie A']}]
```

But to precisely declaring variables we could go with:

```
>>> i=0
>>> lcl = locals()
>>> for key,val in DictionaryA.iteritems():
        lcl["Dict" + str(i)] = {key:val}
        i += 1
```

As can be seen the first 3 `Dict` variables:

```
>>> Dict0
{'Must See': ['Children of Men', 'Skyfall', 'Movie F']}
>>> Dict1
{'Forget It': ['Avenger', 'Movie B']}
>>> Dict2
{'No Rating': ['Hobbit', 'Movie C', 'Movie G']}
```

As mentioned by others, if you want to put it in a function you should add it to the `globals()`:

```
>>> glb = globals()
>>> for key,val in DictionaryA.iteritems():
        glb["Dict" + str(i)] = {key:val}
        i += 1
```