# How to skip a variable value in eval

Tags: python

i have dict and list as bellow

```
a = {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 3}
b = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd', 'eee']
```

I am comparing list `b` in dict `a` and I am printing values of `'aaa'` and `'bbb'`, I dont know how to store values of `aaa=1`, `bbb=2`. I am trying using this code

```
for i in range(0,len(b)):
    if b[i] not in d:
        continue
    else:
        print int(a[b[i]])
```

its printing

```
1
2
```

i want to assign `aaa=1,bbb=2,ddd=0,eee=0`.

And Then when I print `"print aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd"` it should print values. The variables in list `b` can vary, so that I should dynamically assign values which are in `b` not in a to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
a = {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 3}
b = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd', 'eee']
c = dict([(x, a.get(x, 0)) for x in a])

print "%(aaa)s %(bbb)s %(ccc)s" % c
```

Comment: Thanks@lafada.. The output value is what i want, but can u say how to store the values into a dynamic variables instead of one more dict..

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
for key in b:
    print key, a.get(key,0)
```

If you really need those new keys to be into your dictionary, you can do it like this:

```
for key in b:
    if a.get(key) is None:
        a[key] = 0
```

and print after like you normally would:

```
for k,v in a.items():
    print k,v
```

---

**Edit:** From your comment it seems that you're now doing:

```
eval('aaa+bbb+ccc',b)
for key in b:
    if a.get(key) is None:
        a[key] = 0
eval('aaa+bbb+ccc',b)
```

Are you using `eval` for printing? If you are, don't do that! You can find at [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/589206) a more complete discussion about `eval`.

Anyway I'm guessing you might be looking for somthing like:

```
print sum(a[key] for kay in b)
```

But I really don't know. Please edit your question explaining what you're really trying to do (with samples of input and expected output).

Comment: Thanks @riki poggi, but i want to use these values in eval('aaa+bbb+ccc',b)for key in b:
    if a.get(key) is None:
        a[key] = 0
eval('aaa+bbb+ccc',b)

Comment: @user1182090: What are you exavtly trying to do? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9532178/edit) your question and provide more information. Also you should not use `eval` as explained in the link I provided above.

Comment: sorry @Rik .suppose dict1={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3} and list1=['a','b','c','d']. what i want in output is variables should be dynamically generated and should contain the value of 'a','b' of dict1 because 'a' and 'b' are present in list1 and for 'c' and 'd' it should contain "zero" because 'c' and 'd' of list1 are not in dict so it contains zero. I dont want this output values in different list r in dict, it should be stored in variables. so i can use it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the code to

```
for v in b:
    if v not in a:
        a[v]=0
    print a[v], '=', int(a[v])
```

You could use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) rather than a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks@hochl but can u say how to generate variables dynamically and then i hav to asssign that values for that. For eg by comparing list"b" in dict "a" if key is their it should take that value of key and dynamically generate variable and assign to it. finally elements which r not their in list"b" should be assigned zero and saved

Comment: @user1182090: What you're explaining is a really bad design, why do you need that in the first place?

Comment: You might be interested in reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028785/589206