# Pass a variable in another variable

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically set local variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python)

I tried to execute this :

```
        # the request send a number and its ok, the variable have good informations.
        test = request.POST[member.user.username]

        # SyntaxError at ***here***, can't assign to operator
        group%d % test = member.user.username
```

I have tried also :

```
        test = request.POST[member.user.username]
        group%d = member.user.username % test
```

And :

```
        test = request.POST[member.user.username]
        group%d = member.user.username % (test)
```

Any idea for the syntax ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve whith "group%d" ? The common syntax for formatted strings is: `result = format % (var1, var2)`.

Comment: I want to have variables like group1, group2...

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionnary to do this:

```
test = request.POST[member.user.username]
d={}
d['group'+str(test)]= member.user.username
```

Maybe, there is a better way to do that, but I only know this one.

Comment: It doesn't work with me.. I have found another solution to avoid variable variables :)