# How to set a variable by its name in Python?

Tags: python

EDIT 2 : since so many people are crying against the bad design this usecase can reveal. Readers of these question and answers should think twice before using it

I've trying to set a variable (not property) by it's name in Python :

```
foo = 'bar'
thefunctionimlookingfor('foo', 'baz')
print foot #should print baz
```

PS : the function to access a variable by its name (without eval) would be a plus !

EDIT : I do know dictionary exists, this kind of usage is discouraged, I've choose to use it for a very specific purpose (config file modification according to environment), that will let my code easier to read.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically setting variables in the local scope is not possible in Python 2.x without using `exec`, and not possible at all in Python 3.x.  You can change the global scope by modifying the dictionary returned by `globals()`, but you actually shouldn't.  Simply use your own dictionary instead.

Answer (score 5):

When you want variably-named variables, it's time to use a dictionary:

```
data = {}
foo = 'bar'
data[foo] = 'baz'
print data['bar']
```

Comment: This was not my question, my question was how to set local variables, no how to workaround that need

Comment: @AsTeR: you should accept one of the other answers then.  Also, you should stop trying to do this.  Dictionaries were meant to solve this problem.

Comment: I know dictionary exist, I also know that I should accept answer on SO if any fits my question. And I also know what I do, thanks for caring (the edit of the question explains a bit that point) !

Comment: @AsTeR: Please read Ned's nice blog post [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) (in particular the discussion).  And please consider the possibility that you are wrong on this one.

Comment: I do consider that I might be wrong. I'm not having the usecase described in your article. Tell me your opinion : I've a config.py module, I call 'config.tmpPath' for example, this config has to partially change according to what the user want. I've a dictionnary of dictionnary (one per potential configuration) containing the variable that should be changed. I don't want to have to call config.getMyVar(name, concreteConfig) (I'd lose autocompletion and have a lot more text), I prefer to call config.use(concreteConfig) to update config module variables and then call config.name.

Comment: @AsTeR: In that case, I suggest to make `config` an instance of a custom class, and to use `setattr()` and `getattr()`.  Dynamically named *attributes* have their use cases, but dynamically named *variables* don't.  (This seems to be an instance of the XY problem: You did not ask about your actual problem, but about the attempted solution.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach +1 even if I do not really understand why is it better in a class

Comment: @AsTeR: Modules are not meant to be used that way, so it would surprise readers of the code and users of the library.  Moreover, classes have much better support for dynamic attributes, including the `__getattr__()`, `__getattribute__()` and `__setattr__()` special methods as well as descriptors.

Comment: @AsTeR: Regardless which solution you choose, you need to be very careful since you are mixing namespaces:  the functions/methods to modify the configuration and the configuration variables itself.  In your example, consider what happens if someone sets the variable `use` to some value – subsequent calls to `config.use()` would fail.

Comment: I do, I do, this could also occurs with setattr I think (I do not test)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
def thefunctionimlookingfor(a, b):
    globals()[a] = b
```

Usage:

```
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'q' is not defined
>>> thefunctionimlookingfor('foo', 'bar')
>>> foo
'bar'
```

But this is a terrible idea, as others have mentioned.  Namespaces are a useful concept.  Consider a redesign.

Comment: +1 for detailed code, I accepted Sven's answer for being the first !

Answer (score 1):

At the module level you can use `setattr` on the current module, which you can get from `sys.modules`:

```
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'name', 'value')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `locals()` function returns a dictionary filled with the local variables.

```
locals()['foo'] = 'baz'
```

Comment: That do not work inside of a function indeed, but outside it works

Comment: @AsTeR: Then you should be using `globals()` instead of `locals()`.  The documentation of `locals()` states that the returned dictionary must not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for functions like these? They allow modifying the local namespace you happen to be in.

```
import sys

def get_var(name):
    return sys._getframe(1).f_locals[name]

def set_var(name, value):
    sys._getframe(1).f_locals[name] = value

def del_var(name):
    del sys._getframe(1).f_locals[name]
```