# What's the difference between locals() and globals()

Tags: python

I don't understand what's wrong with in this code.

Please let me know how I write to solve this problem.

I'd thought that this might had been good, but it caused the error.

```
>>> def L():
...     for i in range(3):
...             locals()["str" + str(i)] = 1
...     print str0
... 
>>> L()
```

If I execute it, the following error happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in a
NameError: global name 'str0' is not defined
```

However, if I use `globals()`, the error didn't happen(like the following)

```
>>> def G():
...     for i in range(3):
...             globals()["str" + str(i)] = 1
...     print str0
... 
>>> G()
1
```

But!!! If I don't use for statement, I can write like this and works well.

```
>>> def LL():
...     locals()["str" + str(0)] = 1
...     print str0
... 
>>> LL()
1
```

I want to get the result by using variables set in the method after the above code was executed.

```
>>> str0
1
>>> str1
1
>>> str2
1
```

Comment: Are you just goofing around with this, or are you actually going to use it for something?  If you are going to use the code for something, this is a bad idea.  You should instead use a list, or a dictionary with 0, 1, 2 as the keys.

Comment: Of course I know it's useful to use a list or a dictionary. But I wondered why this error happened.

Comment: Don't do this! You don't have to play around with locals, it is so much simpler to write str[0]=1, str[1]=1, etc. (use lists or dicts, as BrenBarn said). It is always a bad practice to transfer variables into variable names and vice versa. 
However, this issue is still a good lesson to understand how locals work :).

Comment: Thank you! so I understand I should use lists or dictionaries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set local variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation of locals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)

> Note:
>
> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.