# Convert string into integer separated by space

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer

how to extract the integers from the string(integers separated by space) and assign them to different variables.
eg.
Given string: `"2 3 4 5"`
assign: `n=2, m=3, x=4, y=5`

Comment: do you know how many ints in string?

Comment: If you string has non-numeric chars also like `s = "2, 3, 45, a, b,  5,"` then you can use `re.findall(r'\d+', s)` to convert into list of number strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (read comments):

```
>>> s = "2 3 4 5"
>>> s.split()  # split string using spaces  
['2', '3', '4', '5'] # it gives you list of number strings
>>> n, m, x, y = [int(i) for i in s.split()] # used `int()` for str --> int
>>> n            # iterate over list and convert each number into int 
2                # and use unpack to assign to variables
```

Comment: @wolfrevo Then I will use list variable `L = [int(i) for i in s.split()]` now I can use any elements as `L[j]` for `j < len(L)`, Generally in programming languages we uses arrays(or in Python say list) when we need many variables.

Comment: please do see my answer

Answer (score 2):

the number of values in your string might be variable. In this case you could assign the variables to a dictionnary as follows:

```
>>> s = "2 3 4 5"
>>> temp = [(count, int(value)) for count, value in enumerate(s.split(' '), 1)]
>>> vars = {}
>>> for count, value in temp:
...    vars['var' + str(count)] = value
>>> vars
{'var4': 5, 'var1': 2, 'var3': 4, 'var2': 3}
>>> vars['var2'] 
3
```

If you really don't want a dictionnary, you could consider the following:

```
>>> temp = [(count, int(value)) for count, value in enumerate(s.split(' '), 1)]
>>> for count, value in temp:
...     locals()['var{}'.format(count)] = value
>>> var2 
3
```

`locals()['var{}'.format(count)] = value` will add a local variable named 'var{count}' and assign the value to it. `locals()`shows you the local variables and its values.

Remember: do this only if you really know what you are doing. Read please also the note on `locals` in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals): "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: you could write as `var = dict(( "var" + str(count), int(value)) for count, value in enumerate(s.split())`  in one line .... if someone uses Python3 then he can write expression in `{ }` dict compression. ..but your dict idea is good.

Comment: I was about to add same in my answer in `vars()` scope but I read somewhere that behavior is undefined (I guess in Apress). I am not sure about But if it is a defined behavior, then it is very very good answer. I am kinda learn in Python.

Comment: I just [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python) "Modifying locals() is undefined." Oh it is undefined sorry.

Comment: I prefer using dictionnaries or lists. But for some scenarios "dynamic" variables are very useful. BTW: would you mind marking my answer as useful?

Comment: I up-voted your answer already, But I would like to suggest add this line "Modifying locals() is undefined" in your answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I added a reference to locals() in the Python Documentation. Do you have some link explaining with more details why and which parts `locals` are undefined? Are `globals` also undefined?

Comment: :( no I have no other link, (I got like of other answer  that I posted in comment above). But remember some people downvotes for [`modifying locals()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python#comment9828318_8028728)