# Access value of dynamically generated variable

Tags: python

I've a value assigned to a variable and I'm generating variable name by using loops. I wanted to assign the actual value of generated variable. If I follow the below method it is assigning string instead of value.

```
full_C3_sucess = 10
comp_Nonc3 = 100
for stage in ["C3", "Nonc3"]:
    for dtype in ["full", "comp"]:
        deployment = {}
        format = dtype + "_" + stage
        deployment['deployAttempted'] = format + "_sucess"
```

If I print `deployment['deployAttempted']`, it is having the string `full_c3_sucess` instead of it original value. Can somebody help me here.

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables; use a dictionary instead; `items['full_C3_sucess']` is much easier to handle than juggling `locals()` or `globals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- use `eval`: `print eval(deployment['deployAttempted'])` but it is not a good practice.
- use a dictionary
- use `locals()` or `globals()`

You can find on SO [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop). Usually, like Martijn Pieters commented, dictionary is the better choice:

```
mydict['full_c3_sucess'] = 10
...
print mydict[deployment['deployAttempted']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `globals()` and `locals()` to access global and local variables by name: `locals()[format + "_sucess"]`.