# How to convert dictionary mapping to 'integer aliasing'

Tags: python

How would I accomplish the following?

```
>>> x={'NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE': 11}
>>> for k,v in x.items():
...     k=v
... 
>>> NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE' is not defined
```

Basically, I want to be able to convert a dictionary mapping into the following:

```
NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE = 11
...other items...

if content_type == NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE:
    # do something
```

How would this be accomplished from a dict?

Comment: Dynamic variables are almost certainly the wrong approach.  What's wrong with doing `if content_type == x['NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE']:`?

Comment: What is an integer mapping? It looks like you are trying to make constants...

Comment: @mattm I'm not sure what the correct term would be for this but setting a name for an integer so it can be more easily recognized (aliasing) ? For example: `MATTM_USER_ID = 3161282`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set local variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python)

Comment: @David542. Do you mean an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically setting variables is a truly terrible idea in more ways than I can count, but Python gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot!  At an interactive interpreter prompt it may be less horrible than anywhere else...

```
>>> x={'NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE': 11}
>>> vars().update(x)
>>> NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE
11
```

Works in both Python 2 and Python 3 interactive interpreters.

A better approach is to keep each bunch of such names-with-values within a class, which acts as its namespace.  See http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/ -- oldie, but goldie, if I say so myself:-).  Just say, e.g

```
>>> movies = Bunch(**x)
```

and the global variables will be intact but `movies.NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE` will be `11` with zero risk of "namespace pollution" (the big problem with dynamically setting global variables)...

Comment: Why would it be such a bad idea if the variable names are super-specific and would never be overwritten? For example, I have a list of 'content types' that I use through the application. So having access to `CONTENT_TYPE_SHORT_FILM` is much more readable than doing anything else. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @David542 - Accidentally overwriting the names is just one of the problems.  They also pollute the global namespace.  Plus, it's hard to work with them as a whole.  I mean, with the dictionary, you can get its length, add and remove items easily, print it, iterate over it, etc.  Dynamic names however are just names.

Comment: A far superior approach is to keep each logical group of such constants in a class -- see e.g http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/ ... oldie but goldie, if I say so myself:-).  This will avoid just about every problem connected with making such constants into global variables!  `import this` at a Python interpreter prompt -- each line is a gem of wisdom, but this is about the last, subtlest one...: "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!".  Keep bunches of name in a namespace: you'll live happier and saner!-)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x={'NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE': 11}
>>> g = globals()
>>> for k, v in x.items():
...  g[k] = v
...
>>> NON_EPISODIC_MOVIE
11
>>>
```