# Create a variable from a value stored in a variable in python

Tags: python

In python I have:

```
var = "abc"
```

How can I create a dictionary of name `abc` using `var` ?

Comment: to make the question more clear, could you give us a dictionary that you seek ?

Answer (score 2):

`globals()` method returns a dictionary that contains all the names of global scope. You can use this to create a variable whose name is stored in another variable. Something like this:

```
>>> var = 'abc'
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'var': 'abc', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> globals()[var] = {}
>>> abc
{}
>>> globals()
{'abc': {}, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'var': 'abc', '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> abc['p0'] = 2
>>> abc
{'p0': 2}
>>>
```

Comment: locals() is the safer choise if used in a scope.

Comment: @Iskren I originally mentioned `locals()` but later found that it has problem as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/377953

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Assign var to a dictionary where 'name' evaluates to 'abc'? In that case,

```
var = {'name': 'abc'}
```

Otherwise, I have no idea what you're asking.