# setting user input to variable name

Tags: python

I am using python and would like to know if it would be possible to ask the user for the name of a variable and then create a variable with this name. For example:

```
my_name = input("Enter a variable name") #for example the user could input orange
#code to set the value of my_name as a variable, say set it to the integer 5
print(orange) #should print 5 if the user entered orange
```

I know it can be done using a dictionary but I would like to know whether this is possible without creating an additional object. I am using python 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the dictionary returned by a call to `globals()`:

```
input_name = raw_input("Enter variable name:") # User enters "orange"
globals()[input_name] = 4
print(orange)
```

If you don't want it defined as a global variable, you can use `locals()`:

```
input_name = raw_input("Enter variable name:") # User enters "orange"
locals()[input_name] = 4
print(orange)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. However do I always have to do it with globals()?

Comment: I'm not aware of any simpler way to achieve what you ask than via `globals()` or `locals()`.

Comment: `locals` isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: If the assignment and use are in the same lexical scope, then yes, it is.

Comment: How do you access this variable later in the code without knowing the user input beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is outside a function, you can do it by modifying locals.

```
my_name = raw_input("Enter a variable name")  # Plain input() in Python 3
localVars = local()
localVars[my_name] = 5
```

If you're inside a function, it can't be done. Python performs various optimizations within functions that rely on it knowing the names of variables in advance - you can't dynamically create variables in a function.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/901641

Comment: This answer works outside a function. You said that it is not possible to do it inside a function but the answer by @EvenLisle works inside a function as well. Could you please explain why this happens?

Comment: @AbdulHadiKhan: You're modifying globals in his case. Python takes a lot longer to access global variables than local variables.