# Need function to assign object name in class

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to make a class, `Player`, and I'd like the user to create objects, say to add to their team.

Every tutorial will have something like this to create new players, say Jordan.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

p1 = Player('Jordan')
p2 = Player('Kobe')
```

But I want the user to have the ability to create new players, and they're not going to code, right? 
And I would rather the object variable be just the player name, like, "Jordan", or "Kobe".

So if everything was manual, I could say,

```
jordan = Player('Jordan')
kobe = Player('Kobe')
```

So to come up with a function to have users create players, what should it look like? And what would the variable be? Any way to get it assigned as the player name? Or at least a serialized number like p1, p2, p3, ...?

```
def create_player():
    new_player = input("Which player would you like to create? ")
    name_of_variable_for_player = Player(new_player)
```

Ok, so follow on question.

What happens when you just have a static variable in the create function?

```
def create_player():
    p = Player(input("What player would you like to make? ")
```

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824194/setting-user-input-to-variable-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) e.g. `roster = {}; name = 'Jordan'; roster[name] = Player(name)`

Comment: wjandrea, I'm not sure what you're suggesting? Does all that go on one line? or sequentially down a line at every ";"?

Comment: @StuNami OK, I'll write you an answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the "static variable in the create function" since `p` is lost as soon as the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict instead of dynamic variables. For more details see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

In this case that might look something like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):  # Adding this for better output
        cls_name = type(self).__name__
        return '{}({!r})'.format(cls_name, self.name)

my_team = {}
name = input("Which player would you like to create? ")
my_team[name] = Player(name)
print(my_team)
```

Example run:

```
Which player would you like to create? Shaq
{'Shaq': Player('Shaq')}
```

How to turn that into a function might vary based on what you're trying to do, but you could start here:

```
def add_player_to_roster(roster):
    name = input("Which player would you like to create? ")
    roster[name] = Player(name)

my_team = {}
add_player_to_roster(my_team)
print(my_team)
```