# converting string to my datatype in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

Lets say I have a simple console program where user can input some text.
And suppose I have class as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_string):
        self.lens=len(some_string)
    
    def PrintLen(self):
        print(self.lens)
```

Suppose that user input some text consisting of only one word (lets say - `'word'`).
My question is how can I make `'word'` to become instance of `class A` that I can use `word.PrintLen()` without any errors? I guess I should implement some function that converts string object to my class object but I don't know how to realize that.

Comment: it would be far better to use the user input as a key into a dictionary, and the new instance to be the value.

The problem you have is when you type 'word.Printitem()` in your code you have already determined the name of your instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A far better solution instead of trying to create a new variable based on whatever the user inputs, it would be more 'sensible' to make use of dictionaries.

A dictionary contains pairs of keys and values so your key would be the input value and the value would be the instance of class.

your code would be like this :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_string):
        self.lens=len(some_string)

    def PrintLen(self):
        print(self.lens)

instances = {}
name = input('WHat is your name >')
instances[name] = A(name)
```

you will then use it like this :

```
instances[name].PrintLen()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sensing some anti-patterns here. The key thing you're looking to do based on your question is set the user's input to the name of a variable - of an instance of your class. I don't know if that's necessarily the best way to do it for your use case. Maybe it could be better to always name the variable the same thing but add a self.string parameter to your A class.

If you do want to do that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824194/setting-user-input-to-variable-name). You would write

```
in_string = raw_input("Enter string:")
locals()[in_string] = A(in_string)
```

Then you could call the PrintLen function as you described.

Comment: using locals like that is horrible - uggh.