# Can't access variable created by altering locals() inside function

Tags: python, locals

I need to assign some variables when calling a funcion with the name of the variable as an argument.

Therefore, I loop through a tuple with the desired names, assigning them via the `locals()` dict.

It works, but then I can't access them by name - even inside the function itself.

```
def function():
    var_names = ("foo","bar","foobar")
    for var_name in var_names:
        locals()[var_name] = len(var_name)
    print foo
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    function()
  File "error_test.py", line 5, in function
    print foo
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

With the following code it works well:

```
def function():
    var_names = ("foo","bar","foobar")
    for var_name in var_names:
        locals()[var_name] = len(var_name)
    print locals()["foo"]
```

Isn't it that the `locals()` dict contains just the normal function variables? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Don't expect to reference `foo` by changing a key-value pair in the `locals` dictionary.

Comment: You will run into the same problem if you try to extend the functionality of built-in type classes like `str`

Comment: If you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) of the `locals` function, you'd see that it explicitly warns you about this.

Comment: a useful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Comment: and another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python

Comment: You would use  `exec` if you really wanted to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
for var_name in var_names:
    locals()[var_name] = len(var_name)
```

You modify the `locals()` dictionary:

as @user2357112 [aptly linked in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

> Note
>
> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

So modifying `locals()` deletes the local variables, hence the `NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined` error.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this post](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html), the explanation seems to be that inside the function **you're only retrieving a copy of the namespace** and not the namespace itself:

> locals does not actually return the local namespace, it returns a copy. So changing it does nothing to the value of the variables in the local namespace.

I'm still looking for a way to change that namespace inside a function, so I'd love to see someone answer this question with a better solution than this.