# Defining and appending in new list inside a loop using iterator (python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to start and append new lists inside a loop using iterator. I tried to use dictionary idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python).

Here is the snippet of my code, you can ignore the details of the code. If the if condition is satisfied I need to append values of `i` in a specific list, which will be like patch12,patch53 etc:

```
import math as m

d = {}

for i in range(0,10):

     for j in range(0, 10):

          if((m.floor(vector[upper_leaflet[i],0:1]) <= xx[j][0]) & (m.floor(vector[upper_leaflet[i],0:1]) < yy[j][0])):

              d["patch{}{}".format(xx[j][0],yy[j][0])].append(i)
```

Output should be something like if I print `patch52 =  [ 1, 5, 9 ,10]` 
What would be the correct way to do perform this?

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*? You seem to be trying to append to a string, which obviously isn't going to work - what was the expected output?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create dynamic variables with name patch12 or patch53 etc. This can not be done just by formatting a string. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable) thread where dynamic variable creation is explained.

However, its not a good programming practice. Correct solution could be to use a dictionary or a list.
example:

```
patches = {}
for i in range(0,10):

     for j in range(0, 10):

          if((m.floor(vector[upper_leaflet[i],0:1]) <= xx[j][0]) & (m.floor(vector[upper_leaflet[i],0:1]) < yy[j][0])):

              key_name = "patch{}{}".format(xx[j][0],yy[j][0])
              #if key already exists, append to that list, if not create new list
              if key_name in patches:
                    key_value = patches[key_name]
              else:
                    key_value = []
              #appending newly value ..
              key_value.append(i)
              patches[key_name] = key_value
```

Further , in your program when you need to use this data, either your can iterate through dictionary to find out all keys
ex:

```
for patch in patches:
    do something...
```

or you can directly access value of a particular key (ex: `patch52` by

```
value = patches['patch52']
```

which will give you a list of values corresponding to patch52
ex:

```
print(patches['patch52'])
[1,4,7,9]
```

Comment: Oh and yes: this code is broken, `list.append()` returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `collections.defaultdict` makes things easier:

```
import math as m
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0,10):
     for j in range(0, 10):
          if ((m.floor(vector[upper_leaflet[i],0:1]) <= xx[j][0]) & (m.floor(vector[upper_leaflet[i],0:1]) < yy[j][0])):
              d["patch{}{}".format(xx[j][0],yy[j][0])].append(i)
```