# Array Variable name change

Tags: python, variables, iteration

I want to have a variable number of variables with the variables equal to an array of numbers. I know similar questions have been asked but none provided the answer I was seeking.I have tried having the variables top and bottom either tuples or numpy arrays but neither worked. I don't care what the type of numbers are because I can convert them later, I just need the variable names changed with each iteration.

```
i=[0] 
for x in i:
     top= (1,1,1)
     bottom= (1,1)

     top[i]=top
     bottom[i]=bottom
     i.append(x+1)
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Here is an example that probably better explains what I'm trying to do.

```
for x in range(1,4):
       top = (1,1,1)
       bottom = (1,1)

       if x == 1:
             top1 = top
             bottom1 = bottom
       if x == 2:
             top2 = top
             bottom2 = bottom
       if x == 3:
             top3 = top
             bottom3 = bottom
```

In the bottom code I'm creating a new variable with each iteration, but I'm only doing it for a set amount of iterations. How can I do it for an infinite amount of iterations?

Comment: You are using tuples, and not list. Try with [1,1,1]. Do you realize you are trying to make a recursive list?  BTW what is the question?

Comment: Indexing a list with a list isn't going to work either.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  I tried [1,1,1] and I got " TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not lists " . The question is how do I assign top to top1, top2, top3 as the iterations go by. The same for bottom.

Comment: "I want to have a variable number of variables" What are you asking here? "I have tried having the variables top and bottom ..." And what is this even supposed to mean? I can't understand your question as written.

Comment: I know that the value of top and bottom do not change, so top1 is going to equal to top2 , top3 and so on. But I still want to learn how to name change through iteration.

Comment: I'm probably asking the question incorrectly but that's because I'm still new to coding. I'm trying to create new variables with each iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "new variables" or "name change" [on each iteration]. Taken literally these things aren't possible, but perhaps you didn't mean what you (literally) wrote.

Comment: Also, are you aware that you're probably going to get unexpected behavior due to modifying the list `i` [while iterating across it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097)? As written isn't this an infinite loop due to the append on the last line?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I hope the above edit helps.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, now that you edited to say "How can I do it for an infinite amount of iterations?" that's... an advanced topic. And **not advisable**. This is almost certainly not what you want to do. To learn more about it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028708/).

Comment: You could probably accomplish your overall goal (whatever it is) via [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), although I suspect this still isn't the best approach to whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example you provided, its behavior will most likely not be what you expected because you modify the list `i` while [simultaneously iterating across it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097).

As for your second example, what you're asking is **not advisable** and almost certainly not what you actually want to do. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028708/) for more information.

Finally, I doubt this is actually the best approach for solving your problem, but you can accomplish (approximately) what you were trying to do in your question using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
d = {}
v1 = (1,1,1)
v2 = (1,1)

for x in range(4):
    key1 = 'top' + str(x)
    d[key1] = v1
    key2 = 'bottom' + str(x)
    d[key2] = v2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers and effort. I thought it was more elegant to have an infinite loop with an eventual break, but it seems the non-infinite method is safer and easier to handle. Thanks again.

Comment: @faiz that depends entirely on what condition you'd like to break on. What did you have in mind?