# Python Script to loop through and create variables

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have a massive block of code that creates the following arrays (Var1 ... Var100). I was wondering if there is way to actually write a python script to create and execute the code within a for loop. However, I've been unsuccessful so far in doing so.

```
Var1 = np.where((df['Q_1'] * df['CapR1'])>=(1*df['CapR1']),df['CapR1'],0)
Var2 = np.where((df['Q_2'] * df['CapR2'])>=(1*df['CapR2']),df['CapR2'],0)
...
Var100 = np.where((df['Q_100'] * df['CapR100'])>=(1*df['CapR100']),df['CapR100'],0)
```

I've tried the following but doesn't work:

```
for i in range(1,101):
    'Var' + str(i) = np.where((df['Q_' + str(i)] * df['CapR' + str(i)])>=(1*df['CapR' + str(i)]),df['CapR' + str(i)],0)
```

Comment: why not store your results in a list? then you can do the whole thing in a list comprehension or a `for` loop.

Comment: Agree with @ialarmedalien. The linked answers have interesting magic, but a list is better...

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable It should be helpful