# Assignment to variable using locals()

Tags: python

Why is this not working? All variables below in print statement evaluate to None.

```
def assign(data):
    first=middle=last=suffix=None
    sep = ','
    fields = ['last','first','middle','suffix']
    a = data
    for name in fields:
        if a: 
            a, *b = a.split(sep)
            print('intermediate: ', a, b)
            if a:
                locals()[name] = a
                a = None
                if b:
                    a = sep.join(b)
    print('first %s middle %s last %s suffix %s ', first, middle, last, suffix)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = 'Jon, Bon, Jovi'
    assign(data)
```

---

### Edit 1

Evan asked so posting non working code below. Caveat: I fully understand now that there is no good reason to have varying variables ;)

```
def assign(data):
    first=middle=last=suffix=None
    sep = ','
    fields = ['last','first','middle','suffix']
    a = data
    for name in fields:
        if a: 
            a, *b = a.split(sep)
            print('intermediate: ', a, b)
            if a:
                #locals()[name] = a
                exec('%s = a' % name)
                a = None
                if b:
                    a = sep.join(b)
    print('first %s middle %s last %s suffix %s ', first, middle, last, suffix)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = 'Jon, Bon, Jovi'
    assign(data)
```

Comment: You can't use `locals()` that way.  The locals of a function are not actually kept in a dictionary, so `locals()` has to synthesize one for you - but there's no transfer in the opposite direction.

Comment: `locals` is one of those functions which, if you are using, indicates you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Here, don't define 4 different local names; define a single local `dict` with 4 keys.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, its greatly appreciated. I want those string-stored variables (in any form) to dynamically get those values. The values are computed correctly, its now a question of assignment. Anyone want  to take a stab at fixing this function to make it work? You probably see my intent.

Comment: Or better yet, `def assign(first=None, middle=None, last=None, suffix=None): ...`, then call with `assign("Jon,Bon,Jovi".split(","))`.

Comment: @ImpostorSyndrome yes, **use a dict** don't dynamically create variables. There is almost *never* a good reason to.

Comment: Warning heeded! The original to this post which has been marked duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable)  has some good answers. I am either going to return a 4 tuple from the function or use setattr on an object or use a dict.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pythonic way to assign values to local variable names dynamically. If you want this behavior, the simplest solution is to use `exec`.

If you simply replace the line:

```
locals()[name] = a
```

With exec:

```
exec('%s = a' % name)
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for exec while you are at it.

Comment: customary warning about exec/eval being potentially dangerous...

Comment: Evan I tried plugging in exec, it didn't work.

Comment: @ImpostorSyndrome There is no way for anyone to help you without more information. Could you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ImpostorSyndrome a good place to start would be fixing the syntax error in your print statement. "print('first %s middle %s last %s suffix %s ' % (first, middle, last, suffix))"

Answer (score 0):

locals() returns new dictionary data. It can not be reference of stack memory of "assign" function.

I think you want to make a object easily when you create an instance related of name.
How is this code as below:

```
class Name:
    def __init__ (self, data):
        sep = ','
        fields = ['last', 'first', 'middle', 'suffix']
        data = data.split(sep)
        self.fields = {f:d for f, d in zip(fields, data)}

    def __str__ (self):
        orderedFields = ['first', 'middle', 'last', 'suffix']
        output = ''
        for field in orderedFields:
            output += field+' '+self.fields[field]+' '
        return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = Name('Jon, Bon, Jovi, ')
    print (data)
```