# How to set the name of a variable using strings

Tags: python

Currently in my code, I have been using `globals()['value%s' % str(int(y))]` to be able to set a name of a variable using strings, but now I have run into a problem in that this variable is a global and I don't want it to be a global. Is there a way to change the code such that I can create a variable name using a string without creating a global variable?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `dict` for this?

Comment: Why do you want to set a variable name from a string? This is what dicts are for.

Comment: You can't edit local variables dynamically, because they're accessed by index under the hood, not name. Use a dictionary! https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the `locals` dictionary. A more robust and flexible approach would be to use a `dict` local to the function:

```
def foobar():
    dct = {}
    dct[f'value{y}'] = 'something'
    ...
```

Comment: Sol I just tried `locals()['value%s' % str(int(y))] = 8`, and it appears to work. `locals()['value%s' % str(int(y))]' return 8, and `locals()` returns a bunch of variable names including `value5` (as y was 5). So it Python doing something behind my back to fool me into thinking it works?

Comment: @Deepstop Perhaps you've run it outside function? On the module scope, `locals` and `globals` are the same, so setting to `locals` will work there.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.