# Is it possible to create a dataframe name based on concatenated strings in pandass?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to create a new dataframe in python based on concatenated strings. I have a loop and need to set up several dataframes a the output.

So in short is there a way of getting the below to work?

```
a='Blue'
b='Green'

Desired output:

BlueGreen=pd.DataFrame()

or 

a+b=pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically set local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dangerous Way:**

```
exec('%s = %s' % (a+b, pd.DataFrame()))
```

**Safe Way:**

```
d = {}
d[a+b] = pd.DataFrame()
```

Just you have to do:

```
print(d['BlueGreen'])
```

to get the value but you can make it to be accessed regularly, like:

```
locals().update(d)
```

Than you're set.

Comment: Thanks great thanks. I think I'll go for the dangerous way, as its less code and I can follow whats going on better. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, I'm not sure if I'm getting it right or no!?
u can easily concatenate(add them to each other) strings and change it to dataframe like this:

```
//if color is the name of your list of string
d={'input ur header name here': color}
d=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

if i got it wrong, please describe your problem more