# What do I need to do to dynamically import a module?

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
m = importlib.import_module('operator')
eval('operator.add') # returns NameError
```

I know I can use `m.add` but I can't do that as I am reading the input to `eval` from a file. Is there a way I can get `m` to be loaded into the current runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to assign the result of [`import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to a variable named `operator` instead of `m`.

```
operator = importlib.import_module('operator')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
import operator
```

Comment: What if I am importing something else rather than operator? For instance: `m = importlib.import_module(read_input())`

Comment: @JRR In such a case, it's more complicated as you have to dynamically assign a local variable. See: [Dynamically set local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable) So, it will look like `module = read_input()` and then `locals()[module] = importlib.import_module(module)`.