# Adding variables to global space using globals()

Tags: python

i am using globals() and locals() to view the variables in the global and local space. however i am able to add variables to the global space using globals() but not able to add local variables using locals().

```
x=10
def show():
    y=20
    locals()['k']=40
    print(locals()['k'])
    print("k=",k)# generates error
    

show()
print(globals())
globals()['newkey']=77
print(globals())
print("newkey=",newkey)# shows error in editor typing but runs properly
```

how can we add local variable using locals

Comment: Perhaps this can help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/8089674](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/8089674)

Comment: technically you add it but you cannot retrieve its value in that way...

Answer (score 1):

Using `locals`/`globals` dictionary initialization you split the initialization as a key pair, a **string** with the variable identifier and its value. So each time the you need the value you have to deal with a string as a dictionary key or a string to be evaluated.

```
def a():
    locals()['k'] = 40
    print('k' in locals())

    print(f"k={locals()['k']}") # dict-way

    print(f"k={eval('k')}") # eval-way
```

Output

```
True # so it is in the name space!
k=40
k=40
```

**Remark**: if you try to call the variable directly `k` the compiler will complain raising a `NameError: name 'k' is not defined` exception.