# How to assign the output of a function running through a list to a variable?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Say I have a function, denoted by Show, that runs by accessing points in a list. Is it then possible to assign each outcome from the function to a variable? Is it possible for the variable to be defined by dfi so the outputs would be df1, df2, df3, ect... for a long as defined by count?

```
count = 5
for i in range(0, count):
    d = Show(list[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a dict by storing variables as keys. A sample could be like this:

```
count = 5
dic = {}
for i in range(count):
  #create key, that would be the variable
  k = "df{}".format(i)
  dic[k] = show(list[i])
```

And now you can use dict to fetch and use the variables in O(1) which would be same as if you have defined the variables explicitly and stored them.

Comment: The function runs okay with this method but then when I try to draw say df1 outside of the loop it says df1 is not defined

Comment: You have to call `dic['df1']` to get `df1`, as it is stored in the `dic` as a key. You can read more about python dictionaries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) to get started if this is new to you.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic naming could be achieved by using advanced Python features not recommended for normal use (see for instance [Dynamically set local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable)).

If you know the number of elements in advance, you can do

```
df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 = [Show(list[i]) for i in range(5)]
```

If you don't, you're probably better off using a list to store the results.

```
count = 5
d = []
for i in range(0, count):
    d.append(Show(list[i]))
```

which can be more elegantly written

```
d = [Show(list[i]) for i in range(count)]
```

or even a dictionary

```
d = [f"df{i}": Show(list[i]) for i in range(count)]
```