# use strings from a list as object names in Python

Tags: python

I have several files in a folder. I can list them via from `os.listdir(path)`. Now, I'd like to open those files and name the objects ( pandas DataFrame) after their file names (without extension).
Lets say I have `files_list=[file1.csv, file2.csv]`  and now I want to avoid:

`file1=pd.read_csv(file1.csv) ...` 
In case I had 100 files the task would be tedious.
Instead, I'd like something like
`for file in files_list:  file_name = pd.read_csv(file)`

this way I could have something like:
'''
file_name_1 object (DataFrame from the file_name_1.csv)
file_name_2 object (DataFrame frrom the file_name_2.csv)
Any help?

Comment: Can you explain it a bit better, I am a bit confused

Comment: Surely the files are named already? So why do you want to name them again?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable?

Comment: You can set global variables dynamically, and you can set attributes of a class instance dynamically, but not local variables within a function.

Comment: You'd like something like... It should work fine, once you avoid using `file` twice: `for file in files_list:  data = pd.read_csv(file)` would be ok

Comment: I have edited my post, so that it is more understandable. It is not the files that I want to name. but the DataFrames I get from those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionnary like this:

```py
from os.path import splitext

def rm_ext(filename):
    """Returns the filename without its extension."""
    return splitext(filename)[0]

files = {}
for file in files_list:
   files[rm_ext(file)] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

You can then access to `file1` like so `files["file1"]`.