# Insert variable into global namespace from within a function?

Tags: python, namespaces, global-variables

Is it possible to add an object to the global namespace, for example, by using `globals()` or `dir()`?

```py
def insert_into_global_namespace(var_name, value):
    globals()[var_name] = value


insert_into_global_namespace('my_obj', 'an object')
print(f'my_obj = {my_obj}')
```

But this only works in the current module.

Comment: Closing this question as duplicate with the reference is wrong. The other question is about USING global variables not ADDING global variables from a different namespace.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just use the `global` statement.

```
def func():
    global var
    var = "stuff"
```

Comment: What if you don't know the name of the variable until runtime?

Comment: @martineau: In the first place, that wasn't the original question.  Anyway, in general if you're trying to assign to a variable whose name you don't know until runtime, you're probably doing something wrong.  How will you later make use of that variable if you don't know what its name is?  Usually if you're trying to create a variable with a certain name, you're better off making a dictionary and using the "name" as the key.

Comment: Yes, I know that wasn't the original question. As for a realistic use-case, consider a caller telling the function what name(s) to create via arguments and then using them afterwards in the same module with other code that assumes they're defined. A little like at a `from xxx import yyy` statement except `yyy` is a string.

Comment: For that use case, it's still not clear why the caller wouldn't instead pass a dictionary and tell the function to add appropriate keys.  See previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320945/python-using-vars-to-assign-a-string-to-a-variable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python

Comment: No, a more concrete example of the kind of case I was thinking of was would be a function that created a number of named constants for you like say calling `Enum('RED, GREEN, BLUE')` would result in variables of those names being created in the namespace with values equal to 0..2. Yes, these _could_ be put into a dictionary called `colors` and retrieved with an awkward `colors['RED']`, but having them be variables makes it easier (and slightly faster) to access them afterwards -- so why not?

Comment: @martineau: If you're interested in this issue you should make a new question for it, where you'd get a broader range of people responding.

Comment: @martineau: `globals()['varname'] = 'varvalue'`

Comment: @gsk: That well-known technique only inserts names into the namespace of the module in which the function resides which might not be the same one as the caller's.

Answer (score 53):

It is as simple as

```
globals()['var'] = "an object"
```

and/or

```
def insert_into_namespace(name, value, name_space=globals()):
    name_space[name] = value

insert_into_namespace("var", "an object")
```

Remark that `globals` is a built-in keyword, that is, `'globals' in __builtins__.__dict__` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: This is by far the best answer.  No reason to do any weird magic like the other answers suggested.  I'm just sad I didn't see this answer sooner.

Comment: IMO it would be a lot better to give the `name_space` argument to the function a default value of `None` and then, inside the function, use the calling function's globals as the default namespace when nothing else is given. i.e. `if name_space is None: name_space = sys._getframe(1).f_globals`. Doing this would allow this function to be more easily used by other scripts because the way it's currently coded, the default namespace is that of whatever script/module the `insert_into_namespace()` function itself is defined within—so would only be accessible to other functions in that same script.

Comment: Can you give a code example where the default value of parameter `name_space` above and the value of `globals()` in the current scope are different?

Answer (score 28):

But be aware that assigning function variables declared global only injects into the module namespace. You cannot use these variables globally after an import:

```
from that_module import call_that_function
call_that_function()
print(use_var_declared_global)
```

and you get

```
NameError: global name 'use_var_declared_global' is not defined
```

You would have to do import again to import also those new "module globals".
The builtins module is "real global" though:

```
class global_injector:
    '''Inject into the *real global namespace*, i.e. "builtins" namespace or "__builtin__" for python2.
    Assigning to variables declared global in a function, injects them only into the module's global namespace.
    >>> Global= sys.modules['__builtin__'].__dict__
    >>> #would need 
    >>> Global['aname'] = 'avalue'
    >>> #With
    >>> Global = global_injector()
    >>> #one can do
    >>> Global.bname = 'bvalue'
    >>> #reading from it is simply
    >>> bname
    bvalue

    '''
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.__dict__['builtin'] = sys.modules['__builtin__'].__dict__
        except KeyError:
            self.__dict__['builtin'] = sys.modules['builtins'].__dict__
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self.builtin[name] = value
Global = global_injector()
```

Comment: It seems overwrite does not work, any idea how to make it work? `var = 1; Global.var=2 ; print(var)` (prints 1)

Comment: Because `var` is not in the `builtin` namespace, while `Global.var` is. Only the `builtin` namespace is include implicitly everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

A more terse version of [Roland Puntaier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298025/1397061) is:

```
import builtins

def insert_into_global_namespace():
    builtins.var = 'an object'
```

Comment: Out of dozens of "solutions" I tried, this is the ONLY one that actually worked, and is neat!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has explained how to create and set a global variable whose name is itself the value of a variable.

Here's an answer I don't like, but at least it works[1], usually[2].

I wish someone would show me a better way to do it. I have found several use cases and I'm actually using this ugly answer:

```
########################################
def insert_into_global_namespace(
    new_global_name,
    new_global_value = None,
):
    executable_string = """
global %s
%s = %r
""" % (
        new_global_name,
        new_global_name, new_global_value,
    )
    exec executable_string  ## suboptimal!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## create global variable foo with value 'bar':
    insert_into_global_namespace(
        'foo',
        'bar',
    )
    print globals()[ 'foo']
########################################
```

1. Python exec should be avoided for many reasons.
2. N.B.: Note the lack of an "in" keyword on the "exec" line ("unqualified exec").

Comment: You can just do `globals()[new_global_name] = new_global_value`.