# Class and function scope

Tags: python, function, class, oop, instance

I want to create instances of a class from a string user has typed in so I used exec( ) function. The problem is I can't access instance by its name outside the function. My first thought was that it is a problem with scope of a function, and I still think it is but when I put instances in a list I can access them, just not using their name. I'm not really sure what is happening here.. Is there a way so that I could access instances by their name, like `thing1.properties` but outside the function because this is not my whole code so it would be messy to put all outside the function? Something like to create list of instances in a function and to "extract" all instances outside the function so I could access them outside the function. Here is the code:

```
class Things:
    def __init__(self, properties):
        self.properties = properties

listt = []
def create_instance():
    exec("thing1=Things('good')")
    listt.append(thing1)

create_instance()
print listt[0].properties
print thing1.properties
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a very poor way of achieving your goal. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wrote in the question. I want to create instances of a class from a string user has typed in. So when user types in "thing1"  instance thing1 = Things() is created. If there is a better way to do it I would that you share it with me.

Comment: Polluting the global scope is frowned upon in Python. You probably should store your instances at a dictionary instead.

Comment: if you call `locals()` inside your `create_instance` function you will find `thing1` in there... so you want to add your new var to the current `globals()` (which really means into the current module's namespace) which is the same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11813287/202168

Comment: @Anentropic: the exec statement can receive a second argument that is a dictionary used as the scope for the first argument, it defaults to locals() but one can pass globals() instead (but really should not).

Comment: Thank you all, I solved problem by using @PauloScardine suggestion. I stored instances in a dictionary and then I could use dict['thing1'].properties to access instance properties using instance name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I abhor polluting the global namespace, the exec statement can take a second argument to be used as the scope and defaults as `locals()`:

```
>>> def foo(name):
...     exec "{} = 1".format(name)
... 
>>> def bar(name):
...     exec "{} = 1".format(name) in globals()
... 
>>> foo('a')
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> bar('a')
>>> a
1
```

So if you pass `globals` as the scope, it will work as you want, but really? Polluting the global scope by itself is horrid, doing it while evaluating user supplied code is a damn liability.

[update]

> Very helpful! Thank you! But what is now better way of doing it, dictionary or a global scope?

Perhaps you can store all instances into a class variable, for example:

```
class Thing(object):
    instances = {}
    def __init__(self, name, **properties):
        self.name = name
        self.properties = properties
        self.instances[name] = self
    def __repr__(self):
        t = '<"{self.name}" thing, {self.properties}>'
        return t.format(self=self)
```

Now you can do:

```
# declare your things
>>> Thing('foo', a=1, b=2)
>>> Thing('bar', a=3, b=4)

# retrieve them by name
>>> Thing.instances.get('foo')
<"foo" thing, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}>

>>> Thing.instances.get('foo').properties
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

>>> Thing.instances.get('bar').properties
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you! But what is now better way of doing it, dictionary or a global scope?

Comment: @NikolaLošić see my update with a suggested approach