# Access to instance variable, but not instance method in Python

Tags: python, string, class, variables, instantiation

I'm a newbie to python and I think similar question have been asked (including this one: [Can you use a string to instantiate a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python)), but I don't understand the answers or how to apply them.

I'm trying to create multiple instances of a class using what i'll call 'instance names' in a list.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class InstanceNames():
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = ['inst1', 'inst2', 'inst3']

class DoSomething():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        DoSomething.instances.append(self)

instance_names = InstanceNames()
for x in range(len(instance_names.names)):
    print x
    # following line not working at creating instances of DoSomething
    instance_names.names[x] = DoSomething()

print DoSomething.instances
```

I changed the list for loop, and now I'm getting the following output:

```
0
1
2
[<__main__.DoSomething instance at 0x10cedc3f8>, <__main__.DoSomething instance at 0x10cedc440>, <__main__.DoSomething instance at 0x10cedc488>]
```

did it work?  I'm so confused i'm not sure.

Ok. This is some ugly code, but here's what I have now:

```
class InstanceNames():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_names = {'inst1': None, 'inst2': None, 'inst3': None}
        self.o_names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

class DoSomething():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, blah_blah):
        DoSomething.instances.append(self)
        self.name = blah_blah

    def testy(self, a):
        a = a * 2

instance_names = InstanceNames()

for x in range(len(instance_names.i_names)):
    print x
    instance_names.i_names[x] = DoSomething(instance_names.o_names[x])

print "\n"

print DoSomething.instances

print "\n"

for y in DoSomething.instances:
    print y.name
    print y.testy(4)
    print "\n"
```

Here is my output:

```
0
1
2


[<__main__.DoSomething instance at 0x10dc6c560>, <__main__.DoSomething instance at 0x10dc6c5a8>, <__main__.DoSomething instance at 0x10dc6c5f0>]


foo
None


bar
None


baz
None
```

Why is the 'name' variable printing, but the 'testy' method is not?

Comment: thanks.  changed the for loop for the list.  Still not getting what I want.  Would love your help.  Thanks.

Comment: `len(self.names)` should be `len(instance_names.names)`

Comment: Your code edits are not making this any better.

Comment: Once you've dealt with the multiple issues others are pointing out (using `self` outside of the class, missing `f` in `for`, etc), I'd point out two things: 1) To create a variable dynamically, you'd use `exec`, and 2) you should *never ever do that*. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: It didn't work, at least not the way you want it to- you're creating a list of `DoSomething` instances, instead of assigning each to a name like `inst1`. But again- you don't actually want to assign new variables dynamically. If you want to map a string to an instantiated class, use a dictionary like @BrenBarn suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking "how do I take the string 'inst1' and make a variable called 'inst1'".

The answer is that you don't want to do that.  Instead, create a dictionary or list mapping your strings to the objects in question.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320945/python-using-vars-to-assign-a-string-to-a-variable) for some examples.

(If that's not what you're asking please clarify your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have any idea what you are really trying to do, to address your specific code, a list is only a collection of values. What you are treating it like is a dict, which is an association between a key and value.

To make your example work, you would use a dict:

```
class InstanceNames():
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = {'inst1': None, 'inst2': None, 'inst3': None}
```

This will now allow the following expression to succeed:

```
instance_names.names[x] = DoSomething()
```

... Because `names` is now a dict and you are accessing a key and assigning it a value.

Again, I make the disclaimer that I have no idea what this code is trying to do...have the feeling it is probably not good... but not taking the angle of judging it.

Answer (score 1):

`instance_names.names` is a [list](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) which requires numbers as indices. In fact, the TypeError you posted says the same thing.

However, you want to set an element using a string in `instance_names.names[x]` - where `x` is a string. Lists don't allow this, you need to use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for that.

There are several ways to solve your problem:

1. You can use a dictionary for instance_names.names in the first place. Then, however, you must use a reserved object such as `None` as a placeholder for instances that haven't been created yet: ´self.names = {'inst1': None, 'inst2': None, 'inst3': None}`, and you must iterate through the keys of the dictionary:`for x in instance_names.names.keys():`
2. You can use a separate dictionary for the instances and set its content in the loop: `self.instances = {}`. `instance_names.instances[x] = ...`

For further reading about Python's data types, I reccomend [Dive Into Python](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/native-datatypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) to create classes dynamically:

```
type_names = ["Class1", "Class2", "Class3"]
storage = {}
for t in type_names:
    storage[t] = type(t, (object, ), {"your": "instance", "attributes": "here"})

for type_name in storage:
    print type_name, "=>", storage[type_name]
```

Alternately, you can used [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to generate lightweight classes if all you really need is a bunch of attributes.

What you *currently* have is creating three instances of the `DoSomething` class and replacing the string values (which you don't use) in the `InstanceNames` class' `names` attribute with these three instances of `DoSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean `or x`?

`self.names` doesn't exists in scope, use `instance_names.names` instead.