# In python create a list with a variable in the name

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to generate a series of (empty) lists using a for loop in python, and I want the name of the list to include a variable. e.g. y0, y1, y2 etc. Ideally looking something like this:

```
for a in range (0,16777216):
global y(a)=[]
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. See the answers for what to actually do.

Comment: Creating empty data structures you're not immediately going to use is unpythonic. Python is capable of lazy evaluation, especially in its iterative data structures. Take advantage of that!

Comment: My final intention was to fake a table by creating a bunch of lists as the y values and the positions as the x values. Having to use another list seems a little kludgey.

Comment: @schwal: I think most Python programmers will think you've got that exactly backwards.  If you use a `dict` or a list of lists, then that *is* your table-- no fakery required.  In fact, the local variables you want to create would simply live in their *own* `locals()` dictionary.  So under the hood you'd be using the same data structure, just far less conveniently, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @schwal: putting data in the names of variables is kludgey.

Answer (score 9):

why wouldn't you do a dictionary of lists?

```
y = {}
for a in range (0,16777216):
    y[a] = []
```

also for brevity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747827/884453

```
y = {a : [] for a in range(0,16777216)}
```

Comment: Except all the keys are integers, so perhaps a list of lists or sparse array?

Comment: i typo'd that a, it wasn't supposed to be a string. fixed.

Comment: added dict comprehension

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is quite what you want but couldn't you emulate the same behavior by simply creating a list of lists? So `your_list[0]` would correspond to `y0`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: don't.  Instead create a list so that you access the variables with `y[0]`, `y[1]`, etc.  See [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320945/python-using-vars-to-assign-a-string-to-a-variable) for info.

Comment: You should mark this question as a duplicate to the one you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check out defaultdict

```
form collection import defaultdict

# This will lazily create lists on demand
y = defaultdict(list)
```

Also if you want a constraint on the key override the default `__getitem__` function like the following...

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    if isintance(item, int) and 0 < item < 16777216:
         return defaultdict.__getitem__(self, item)
    else:
         raise KeyError
```