# How to dynamically create classes

Tags: python, class, object, dynamic

I am relatively new to Python and am asking myself if it is possible to create classes where names are dynamically created within a function?

Code:

```
def create_dummy_elements():
    rows = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]
    columns = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]

    for r in range (rows):
        for c in range (columns):
            ***** = element(1,1,1,False)
```

My result should be 81 objects of the class "element" named like AA,AB,AC,AD, ...
***** is what I am actually asking for ...

Comment: Do you wanna create a python file with those classes in the file ? or you want to create different instances of that class?

Comment: It would be simpler to set up a dictionary of `element`s indexed by the names you want. Then once it's set up you could say for instance `elems['AA']` to get the `AA` element.

Comment: Your example doesn't illustrate this part "create classes which names are dynamically created within a function"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320945/python-using-vars-to-assign-a-string-to-a-variable

Comment: what You are asking for " if it is possible to create classes which names are dynamically created within a function." can be done with `type` function but example is for different question

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of these objects, but it's not ideal to create variable names dynamically.

Something like this:

```
my_list_of_elements = []
for r in range (rows):
    for c in range (columns):
        my_list_of_elements.append(element(1,1,1,False))
```

Then you can access them by index number, for example: `my_list_of_elements[n]`

or to match the two-dimensional style for loops you have:

```
my_list_of_elements = []
for r in range (rows):
    temp = []
    for c in range (columns):
        temp.append(element(1,1,1,False))
    my_list_of_elements.append(temp)
```

then you can do `my_list_of_elements[i][j]` to access the i-th row and the j-th column.

If you prefer a string index, a dictionary would serve you well:

```
my_dict_of_elements = {}
for r in range (rows):
    for c in range (columns):
        my_dict_of_elements["element"+(r*c+c)] = element(1,1,1,False)
```

which will give you access like this `my_dict_of_elements["element0"]` for example.

As mentioned in the comment by **atomicinf** on this post, you can use the `globals()` dict, but it seems we both agree there are better practices.

Comment: Well, you _can_ create variable names dynamically (playing with the `globals()` dict), but there's really no reason to do that ever.

Comment: Oh forgot about that business, I'll fix my wording, but I don't think I would ever recommend that when you can just use a data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just can create list as suggested **farmerjoe**, but if you really want to add namespases to global, you can do it like

```
class element(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._args = args
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' '.join(map(str, self._args))


rows = ['A','B']
columns = ['A','B']

for r in rows:
    for c in columns:
        exec('%s%s = element(r,c,False)' % (r,c))

print AB
```

output will be

```
A B False
```

Comment: Aswering this way I feel myself handling a hand grenade to a monkey :) What do community think about too mature answers for on newbee's questions?

Comment: Instead of `exec`, you could simply use `globals()[r+c] = element(r, c, False)`. Or better yet, create a reference to globals (to avoid repeatedly calling it, such as `_globals = globals()`), then using `_globals[r+c] = blah blah blah`.

Comment: there is one caveat here, try globals()[4]=5 versus exec('4=5')

Answer (score 0):

Although it's *possible* to create classes and named instance of classes dynamically in Python, doing so is generally frowned upon. It's considered more "Pythonic" and elegant to store collections of such things in a container of some sort such as a list or dictionary, and then access them when necessary by index or key. Here's how that might apply to your problem:

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, name, a=None, b=None, c=None):
        self.name, self.a, self.b, self.c = name, a, b, c
    def __str__(self):
        classname = self.__class__.__name__
        return('{classname}('
               'name={self.name}, b={self.a}, '
               'c={self.b}, d={self.c})'.format(classname=classname,
                                                self=self))
board = {}  # empty dictionary
for row in 'ABCDEFGHI':
    for col in 'ABCDEFGHI':
        name = row+col
        board[name] = Element(name)  # assign a named Element instance

# sample usage
board['AB'].a = 42
print board['AB']  # Element(name=AB, a=42, b=None, c=None)
board['GD'].c = 'something'
print board['GD']  # Element(name=GD, a=None, b=None, c=something)
```

Note: I don't really know what to call most of the attributes of the `Element` class, so am just using `a`, `b`, and `c` in the above for illustration purposes.